# CSS 'visibility:collapse' bug between Safari and Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, html-table, safari

Coding a simple `html` table, I'm running into a surprising rendering bug between browsers.
Because it is so basic, maybe I'm doing something wrong...

When you load this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup), you can see a very simple table (with `html` and `css`).

My objective is to hide the first column.
At first, it seems really simple, add `style="visibility:collapse"`.
Below all `html` code:

```
<table>
    <caption>Superheros and sidekicks</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="visibility:collapse">
        <col span="2" class="batman">
        <col span="2" class="flash">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <th scope="col">Batman</th>
        <th scope="col">Robin</th>
        <th scope="col">The Flash</th>
        <th scope="col">Kid Flash</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Skill</th>
        <td>Smarts</td>
        <td>Dex, acrobat</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It works perfectly in `Chrome`, but doesn't in `Safari`. Don't know for other browser.
Why is that? Is there a hack?
Thanks.

Comment: As for why is that, simply because Apple never cared to implement it. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8735. As mentioned below, applying `display:none` to td:nth-child(3) or whatever may be a passable workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. However my code would have been much more cleaner without this bug...

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's not a bug. The problem is with the table structure. You have 5 columns but `<col span="2">` doesn't work. The property is not `span` but `colspan`. If you write all 5 columns right, the sample works. See here the first column with `Cell 1` is hidden.

```html
<table>
    <caption>Superheros and sidekicks</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="visibility:collapse">
        <col class="batman">
        <col class="flash">
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>Cell 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Batman</th>
        <th scope="col">Robin</th>
        <th scope="col">The Flash</th>
        <th scope="col">Kid Flash</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Skill</th>
        <td>Smarts</td>
        <td>Dex, acrobat</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your example (the first column is hidden/collapse) works in `Chrome` and not in `Safari`. Hence, the bug... :-). Any idea?

Comment: Really? I have no Safari to test. Caniuse.com says it's supported by Safari... Then you could use 'nth-child' to hide the table cells and in this way to hide columns.

Comment: "<col span="2"> doesn't work. The property is not span but colspan." This is wrong. The attribute is `span`.